# Handling javascript dialog box on Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, modal-dialog, alert

I am writing an automation code for a webpage using Selenium webdriver on Python. But, at a certain point it asks for Captcha. So, I decided to manually enter captcha using a javascript dialog box pop-up. But the problem with my code is that for successful implementation it uses wait and automatically accepts the alert box after wait(). And, if I press Enter after entering the Captcha, this error is thrown

> selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Here is my code -

```
def captcha():
    driver.execute_script("var a = prompt('Enter Captcha', '');document.body.setAttribute('data-id', a)")
    time.sleep(7)
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
    driver.find_element_by_id("captcha_code").send_keys(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('data-id'))
    driver.find_element_by_id("captcha_code").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

To improve it I tried this code, in which a *while loop* is checking every second for presence of Alert box, but it isn't working.

```
def captcha():
    driver.execute_script("var a = prompt('Enter Captcha', '');document.body.setAttribute('data-id', a)")
    while EC.alert_is_present():
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Alert Present")
        try:
            driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException:
            print("Error Encountered...")
            continue
        driver.find_element_by_id("captcha_code").send_keys(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('data-id'))
        driver.find_element_by_id("captcha_code").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

It always prints -

> Alert Present

And continues printing this for a long time even if I there is no alert box present.

Comment: Are you using Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I'm using Chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while EC.alert_is_present():
```

To

```
while EC.alert_is_present()(driver) :
```

`EC.alert_is_present()` returns a function so it will always evaluate to true